# How do you append html in a variable if it already has HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML saved in a variable. How can I append more HTML after the already existant one. Basically I use an If statment and I don't wanna re-type the code and reassign the whole html.
My code, += gives an error " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token += "

```
var sticky_add_cart_html = '{strip}<div id="bundle-sticky_add_to_cart" style="'+add_to_cart_style+'">'+sticky_select+'<a href="#" style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; font-weight:bold; text-transform: uppercase; color: '+add_to_cart_color+'; background-color:'+add_to_cart_bg_color+'; border: '+add_to_cart_border+';width:80%; float:left; margin-top:17px" id="bundle-sticky_submit">Add to cart</a></div>{/strip}';
        if ($('input[name="quantity"]').length()) {
            var sticky_add_cart_html +=  '<div class="product-form__item product-form__item--quantity" style="width:20%;float:left;"> <label for="Quantity">Quantity</label> <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="bundle-sticky-quantity" value="1" min="1" class="product-form__input" pattern="[0-9]*"> </div>';
        }
```

Comment: hahaha another js question where everything is downvoted, wonder why it's only js users who downvote everything, but my guess as to what's wrong would be length doesn't need the `()` and you don't need the `var` inside the if - the variable is already declared

Comment: @Pete its not only the js users who downvote, and its probably downvoted as much as it is because of an oversight on the code, or lack of googling

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I pretty much stick to 4 tags in so and by far the most downvotes for no good reason is for js questions - I have put up many answers that answer an OPs problem but as it is not done in the way a js "master" likes to do it, it gets downvoted - even though it is still correct, but just another way of doing things.  That's why I laugh at the js users, very toxic indeed, although I do agree, this whole site is heading that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-declaring the variable, on the third line in your example your have `var sticky_add_cart_html ....`, change it so it doesnt have the `var` instead

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining your variable in your if statement

Try this :

```
var sticky_add_cart_html = '{strip}<div id="bundle-sticky_add_to_cart" style="'+add_to_cart_style+'">'+sticky_select+'<a href="#" style="display: inline-block; padding: 10px; font-weight:bold; text-transform: uppercase; color: '+add_to_cart_color+'; background-color:'+add_to_cart_bg_color+'; border: '+add_to_cart_border+';width:80%; float:left; margin-top:17px" id="bundle-sticky_submit">Add to cart</a></div>{/strip}';
    if ($('input[name="quantity"]').length()) {
        sticky_add_cart_html +=  '<div class="product-form__item product-form__item--quantity" style="width:20%;float:left;"> <label for="Quantity">Quantity</label> <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="bundle-sticky-quantity" value="1" min="1" class="product-form__input" pattern="[0-9]*"> </div>';
    }
```